# Unknown option "documentclass"

Tags: pandoc

I'm using a fresh install of both pandoc and texlive. I have a wrapper script that looks like this...

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=pdflatex \
        --template=default.latex \
        --documentclass=tufte-book \
        --defaults=/home/steve/docs/jma/defaults/book.yaml \
        --verbose \
        --variable pagesize=letter \
        -o tufteoutput.pdf \
        *.md
```

When I run it, I get the following error...

```
Unknown option --documentclass.
Try pandoc --help for more information.
```

When I try to move the documentclass to the YAML file, I get...

```
Aeson exception:
Error in $: Unknown option "documentclass"
```

I've checked spelling and syntax repeatedly, and also updated all my software.

Edit: YAML file...

```
from:  markdown
to:  PDF
toc:  true
verbosity:  INFO
log-file:  TCM_$1.log
notes-after-punctuation:  true
```

Comment: What's in /home/steve/docs/jma/defaults/book.yaml?

Comment: have you tried `--variable documentclass=tufte-book`? According to the pandoc documentation, `documentclass` is **not** a commandline option, but a "variable" for processing documents via TeX.

Comment: That does get rid of the documentclass error. I had a surprisingly hard time finding documentation on how to implement documentclass, so it makes sense that I was doing that step wrong. Thanks! However, I'm not out of the woods. I continue to get Aeson exceptions due to either fontfamily or lang in my YAML file, which I added in above.

Comment: I continued to pull things out of the YAML file to see what happened. Most recently, I got the error "pdf-engine pdflatex is not compatible with output format PDF." That's a new one.

Comment: This might be the time to mention that I did the manual install of vanilla texlive on Debian, and then used apt-get to install pdflatex. That may have introduced some sort of incompatibility. But, the texlive install was only a week ago, and apt-get has my system as updated as possible.

Comment: your installation is broken, if you installed texlive from tug you would have pdflatex. by using apt you have installed a completely separate texlive. check which you are now using.

Comment: Or just remove all the related Debian packages. The vanilla will be newer or at least as new as the .deb packages even using the unstable Sid,  and by default, it is a full installation, so if you did in this way, there is no risk of missing the installs the tufte classes or anything else.

Comment: I got so fed up I reinstalled the entire OS. (I only installed it a week ago.) Now I have a brand-new Debian install, with only vanilla texlive and pandoc. And it STILL gives me really weird errors, which seem bizarre and inconsistent. I know the reason to use the vanilla install is to have the newest releases, but I'm beginning to wonder if maybe they're *too* new. The Debian version is looking better all the time, especially since tufte hasn't been updated in several years.